# Is it possible to automate adding a watermark to files with Sharepoint?

Tags: automated-tests, sharepoint-2013

I've been tasked with trying to automate a process in Sharepoint where whenever a file is put in a folder a watermark is added to the file.

Is this possible?  Does anyone know how to do it?

I've identified where in the process the function would best be placed, but I am new to Sharepoint and am having trouble finding any information relevant to the task.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add Watermarks to Microsoft Word Documents with Power Automate.

[image]

For more detail information, please refer to: https://www.encodian.com/blog/add-watermarks-to-microsoft-word-documents-with-power-automate/

Comment: Does power automate integrate with Sharepoint?  Ideally, I am trying to find a way to do it without plug-ins or third-party apps.